# Funcion onclick no me reconoce parametro

Tags: javascript, axios, delete

mi problema es que intento pasar como parámetro un elemento de un array en un foreach pero me dice Uncaught SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal y solo me señala la linea 1 del codigo de html :| aqui el codigo para que logren entenderlo mejor.
Muchas gracias de antemano!

```js
function getUserts() {

    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/listado')
        .then((result) => {

            let data = result.data


            data.forEach(elemento => {



                tabla.innerHTML += `<tr>
            <th>${elemento.nombre  } 
            <a onclick="editarMateria()" id="editar" class="btn btn-light"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pencil" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.146.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-10 10a.5.5 0 0 1-.168.11l-5 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.65-.65l2-5a.5.5 0 0 1 .11-.168l10-10zM11.207 2.5L13.5 4.793 14.793 3.5 12.5 1.207 11.207 2.5zm1.586 3L10.5 3.207 4 9.707V10h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.293l6.5-6.5zm-9.761 5.175l-.106.106-1.528 3.821 3.821-1.528.106-.106A.5.5 0 0 1 5 12.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.468-.325z"/>
                          </svg> </a>
                          <a onclick="borrarMateria(${elemento._id})"  class="btn btn-danger" id="borrar"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-archive-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.643 15C13.979 15 15 13.845 15 12.5V5H1v7.5C1 13.845 2.021 15 3.357 15h9.286zM5.5 7a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-5zM.8 1a.8.8 0 0 0-.8.8V3a.8.8 0 0 0 .8.8h14.4A.8.8 0 0 0 16 3V1.8a.8.8 0 0 0-.8-.8H.8z"/>
                        </svg></a></th>
            <th>${elemento.proveedor}</th>
            <th>${elemento.lote}</th>
            <th>${elemento.retest}</th>
            <th>${elemento.unidad}</th>
            <th>${elemento.stock}</th>

           </tr>`

            })
           

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Comment: Parece que tienes algún error en nombres de variables, mira [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Identifier_after_number#:~:text=The%20JavaScript%20exception%20%22identifier%20starts,(_)%2C%20or%20dollar%20sign%20(%24).).

Answer (score 0):

solo debí agregar la interpolación entre comillas para que no tuviera el problema del error de variable, quedó asi:

```
<a onclick="borrarMateria('${elemento._id}')"  class="btn btn-danger" id="borrar">
```